# The goal is to write down a method for a given string that returns an array of strings by their appereal in the dictionary

Tags: java, string

```
public static String[] dictionary(String s) {
    String []ans=sentence(s);
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
        if(s.length()<ans.length) {
            String temp=s;
            s=ans[i];
            ans[i]=temp;
        }
    }
    int min;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i)<ans[i].charAt(i)) {
            min=s.charAt(i);
        }else if(ans[i].charAt(i)<s.charAt(i)) {
            min=ans[i].charAt(i);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<ans[i].length();i++) {
        System.out.println(ans[i].toLowerCase());
    }
    return ans;
}
```

on a given string i gotta return an array of sorted strings lexicographically without duplications,without using sort library,stringtokenizer and split method for arrays.
i'm having trouble to sort the given string and connecting it to array of strings.

Comment: This reads very much like homework, which is against guidelines. Is this the case?

Comment: No,i'm exercising string methods

Comment: Haha, it reads oddly specific, but I have no reason to distrust you. I strongly suggest you change the question title to something shorter and more meaningful to get better help.